# Create new array without impacting values from old array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a copy of existing array and remove some items from array copy without impacting the original. I've tried this :

```
var new_arr = old_arr; //when I remove from new array the items from old array are also removed
```

How do I create entirely new copy of the existing array?

**Update :**

When I do this :

```
var new_arr = old_arr.slice();
```

then later :

```
new_arr[0].shift();
new_arr[1].shift();
```

The items from old_array get removed. This is a two dimensional array.

Comment: Unlike an Array filled with simple values, your array is two-dimensional, i.e. it's filled with *object references*. Cloning it using `.slice()` will copy those references – but `new_arr[0]` will still refer to the same object as `old_arr[0]`.

Comment: Voting to reopen, because it's a duplicate of another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object

Comment: @fanaugen how do I make a copy of two dimensional array then?

Comment: @London see @sourcecode's answer below. With jQuery and `JSON.stringify` deep cloning is a snap.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use **two** methods, this:

```
function clone (src) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(src));
}
```

or this:

```
var newArray = oldArray.slice();
```

Comment: Why would you need jQuery for the first solution?

Comment: I like the method with JSON, it is so simple and beautiful !

Comment: Thanks, in my case, only the fist method works

Comment: The JSON method may be simple, but it is veery sloooow, and it will fail completely if your array contains circular elements - e.g. JSX...so need to be very careful with that one!

Answer (score 11):

A newer solution to do this is to use 'from' like this:

```
const newArr = Array.from(oldArr);
```

But this is a shallow copy and if nested elements are mutated they will project in the new created array with from. Best solution then would be to use

```
const newArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldArr));
```

but also that method doesn't ensure all. If for example an element of the array contains a function like n => ++n then it will be null after using the JSON methods so best solution is deepClone and for that full explanation I refer to

[Creating JavaScript Arrays](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/https-medium-com-gladchinda-hacks-for-creating-javascript-arrays-a1b80cb372b/)

Answer (score 2):

Using Yoshi answer you can extend Array prototype (just a simple helper):

```
Array.prototype.clone = function() { 
      return this.slice(0); 
}
```

Comment: It doesn't help here, as the OP needs a deep clone.

Comment: Yes you are correct, but London later updated his question that array is two dimensional.

Comment: Two-dimensianal, yes, that's exactly why your solution won't help.

Comment: Yes, that's why my splice won't help. I posted this answer before London updated his question.

Comment: Oh, I see. You need to either edit your answer according to the updated question or remove it completely.

Comment: Please edit your answer as it may mislead people - given the OP's updated question.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, a two-dimensional array is just an array of arrays. Therefore, cloning one dimension is not enough. We also need to clone all the sub-dimension arrays. Here’s how we do it:

```js
function cloneGrid(grid) {
  // Clone the 1st dimension (column)
  const newGrid = [...grid]
  // Clone each row
  newGrid.forEach((row, rowIndex) => newGrid[rowIndex] = [...row])
  return newGrid
}

// grid is a two-dimensional array
const grid = [[0,1],[1,2]]
newGrid = cloneGrid(grid)

console.log('The original grid', grid)
console.log('Clone of the grid', newGrid)
console.log('They refer to the same object?', grid === newGrid)
---
The original grid [ [ 0, 1 ], [ 1, 2 ] ]
Clone of the grid [ [ 0, 1 ], [ 1, 2 ] ]
They refer to the same object? false
```

Or if we take avantage of [ES6 Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) operation, we can make `cloneGrid` function even simpler:

```
const cloneGrid = (grid) => [...grid].map(row => [...row])
```

For more expanded answer read [How to make a copy of an array in JavaScript](https://ozmoroz.com/2020/07/how-to-copy-array/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try .concat()

```js
var old_arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
var new_arr = old_arr.concat()

console.log(old_arr) //1,2,3,4,5
console.log(new_arr) //1,2,3,4,5

new_arr.shift()

console.log(old_arr) //1,2,3,4,5
console.log(new_arr) //2,3,4,5
```

Answer (score -1):

you may create a new array by using the spread operator. You can also find more about spread operator [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```
cosnt oldArr = [{id: 1, name: 'Ali'}, {id:2, name: 'Raza'}];
cosnt newArray = [...oldArr];
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Spread operator will only work if the array contains primitive data types, in your example the newArray still points to the old objects inside the array